# Where is Malborn?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In the second part of the quest "Diplomatic Immunity" ("Meet Malborn in Solitude"), I cannot find him in the Winking Skeever Inn. I tried looking for him at every hour of the night and day, with no luck. Where is he?

**Note**: I never seen him before and I haven't killed him. Also I haven't yet used console commands with this save.

Comment: Do you have all the unofficial patches installed? They fix many quest bugs.

Comment: No, I didn't. @SevenSidedDie: is there any method to reset the quest? i tried "resetquest mq201" but its just deleted. because of i can not start the quest again, i tried "startquest mq201" but it didn't start.

Comment: There is no way to actually restart/reset quests. That's one of the few unalterable parts of a save file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Malborn is *supposed* to automatically move to a table in a dark corner of the Winking Skeever when you proceed the quest correctly, but if he doesn't, he can probably still be found around town. You may also wish to check the New Gnisis Cornerclub in Windhelm; it's where he tends to go after the quest is complete, and he may have ended up there early by accident.

Alternately, if you are on the PC version, you can try opening the console and typing

```
prid 33f46
moveto player
```

This should find Malborn wherever he is and move him to your location.

**Edit:**
It looks like Malborn doesn't even exist until the quest; it literally spawns him in as you get the objective, and then attaches the correct scripts. If the `prid` command fails, then it's likely that Malborn simply never spawned at all correctly. In that case, you can try either reloading a save from before you talked to Delphine, or try using some combination of

```
setstage mq201 30
setstage mq201 40
```

The first will reset the quest to immediately before Delphine tells you to talk to Malborn, the second grants the "Meet Malborn in Solitude" objective. You may just need to run the second, maybe both, maybe just the first, and then talk to Delphine; without my own game showing the same bug, I can't be entirely certain.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But when i trying to enter "prid 33f46" it says: "Item 33f46 not found for parameter ObjectRefrenceID" What i have to do?!

Comment: I tried his "BaseID" (00036194) but when i executed "moveto player" it said: "Cannot be Moved"

Comment: I could move him to my nearby using "player.placeatme 00036194". but i can not talk to him. :(

Comment: @AmirrezaNasiri Yeah, moveto won't work with a baseid, only a refid, and placeatme will create a new Malborn NPC, but they probably won't be linked to scripts correctly. I've investigated a bit, will update my answer once I track some stuff down.

Comment: I tried them but nothings happened. the Quest list is same.

Comment: @AmirrezaNasiri Then unfortunately, there's not much that can be done except reloading a save from before you talked to Delphine. You could maybe try looking up the quest stages and advancing along some more, but that whole quest involves Malborn quite a bit, so it probably wouldn't work without just outright skipping that quest altogether.

Comment: I did save the game for more than 130 times. closest save to the quest is 43. Now you think! i have to play that again, what if that doesn't fixed? Maybe i have to download a Completed save just for a Quest. Damn!

Comment: You can't go back stages in quests using setstage. However, you can (carefully! save first!) go forward, so set the stage to just after talking to Malborn, then proceed.

Comment: I did it. but in the 110 stage ( Create a distraction and get away from the party ) i need to take the key from Malborn, from Not existing Malborn!

Comment: Is there anyway to Reset the quest? i tried "resetquest mq201" but its just deleted. and i can not start it again.